# Page curl Transition Between two NSViews

Tags: xcode, curl, nsview

I am developing a catalog sort of app for mac osx. I want to be able to transition between multiple views with a book page curl animation. I would do this with a previous and next button. I know I have to use QuartzCore. I have imported the framework into my project but I am not sure where to go from there. My views can be called view 1 and view 2 for this forum. Thank You!